# Compiling OpenCV with CUDA support in Windows 10

Tags: opencv

Attempting to compile OpenCV with CUDA support in Windows 10.
CUDA is installed correctly.
Keep getting the following error(s) when compiling in Visual Studio. Can anyone suggest next troubleshooting steps?

```
Determining if the include file pthread.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/opencv-master/opencv-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_8068f.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0 /v:m && Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
  Using triplet "x64-windows" from "D:\vcpkg-master\vcpkg-master\installed\x64-windows\"
  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27042 for x64
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
  cl /c /I"D:\vcpkg-master\vcpkg-master\installed\x64-windows\include" /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:classic /MP /Od /Ob0 /Oi /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_8068f.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_8068f.dir\Debug\vc141.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue  /bigobj "D:\opencv-master\opencv-master\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c"
  CheckIncludeFile.c
D:\opencv-master\opencv-master\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory [D:\opencv-master\opencv-master\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_8068f.vcxproj]
```

Comment: This [opencv github comment](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/2216#issuecomment-519035177) suggests that the actual problem is not in the logs you've shown.

Comment: I am getting a similar error. Did you solve it?